# Get missing nodes in hierarchy column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with hierarchy column which consists of numbers separated by colons, as well as number of current node and its parent:

```
id = '3:234:657:978' 
currNode = 978
parent = 657
```

I also have a query which returns id's and some other columns from other tables, but some of the links are missing, for example 2 rows are returned, one with id of `3:234` and another one of id `3:234:567:890`. I need the row with `3:234:567` id to form a hierarchy, but it`s not returned.

How can I join the table so I get the missing nodes (with fields other than id being NULL), but only the missing ones (excluding the ones which are not needed to form the hierarchy, e.g. are below the tree of the returned results)?

EDIT:
Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE ids (
id VARCHAR(100)
, currNode INT PRIMARY KEY
, parent INT
, name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE someotherdata (
data VARCHAR(10)
, currnode INT
);

INSERT ALL 
INTO ids(id, currnode, parent, name)
VALUES('3', 3, NULL, 'Node1')
INTO ids(id, currnode, parent, name)
VALUES('3:4', 4, 3, 'Node2')
INTO ids(id, currnode, parent, name)
VALUES('3:4:5', 5, 4, 'Node3')
INTO ids(id, currnode, parent, name)
VALUES('3:4:5:6', 6, 5, 'Node4')
INTO ids(id, currnode, parent, name)
VALUES('3:4:5:6:7', 7, 6, 'Node5')
SELECT * FROM dual; COMMIT;

INSERT ALL
INTO someotherdata (name, id)
VALUES('data1', '3:4')
INTO someotherdata (name, id)
VALUES('data2', '3:4:5:6')
SELECT * FROM dual; COMMIT;
```

Desired result (id is given as parameter to the query, here it equals to '3'):

```
id       name     data

3        Node1    NULL
3:4      Node2    data1
3:4:5    Node3    NULL
3:4:5:6  Node4    data2
```

(3:4:5:6:7 is excluded from the result since it is not needed to form hierarchy with records that return data)

Comment: Can you provide some data samples, your output and the requested output ? it's a little bit hard to understand without them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so nice. but seems to work:

```
SELECT it.id, it.name, ost.data
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.name
FROM ids t JOIN someotherdata st
 ON instr(':'||st.currnode||':', ':'||t.currnode||':') >0) it LEFT JOIN someotherdata ost
ON it.id = ost.currnode
```

---

**Edit** ok, this is nicer:

```
select distinct t.id, t.name, st.data
from ids t left outer join someotherdata st on t.id = st.currnode
start with t.id in (select ist.currnode from someotherdata ist)
connect by prior t.parent = t.currnode
order by t.id
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a66c8/2)

Comment: This won't work if the id's form a tree-like structure, will it? (e.g. there is 3:4:5:6:7, but there also might be 3:4:10:11 and 3:1:34 and so on. The only sure thing about this hierarchy is that currnode and id is unique.

Comment: @kyooryu, I see what you mean, updated my answer (and sqlfiddle demo)